# How would you move a small vehicle a relatively short distance

Tags: towing, fix-a-flat

I'm buying a honda and the owner said it doesn't start( it's 400$ so worth it)  and am trying  to  figure out a few things  1 would be  what are some things to check on it since it hasn't been started and running  in 2 years (would I need new gas)  what can I use to inflate one tire. And in case it truly does need more work done to it how can I move it about 5 blocks without  a  tow dolly.

Comment: If the engine doesn't crank might be the battery, if it does there are might be several causes like faulty spark plugs, clogged fuel injectors/carburetor, crank shaft sensor

Comment: In your opinion  how much do you think max repair cost is  if it doesn't start ??

Comment: There is no way anyone here can answer that question.  If they do, they'll be wrong.  You haven't even given the year and the model of your car.  Does it have an ECU?  Does it have a carburetor?

Comment: 19989 honda civic hatchback  and has a bit under 200000 miles

Comment: Duplicate of http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/24916/675

Comment: I made that post but added more derail since I posted that one in the wrong section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There definitely is risk purchasing something without knowing the condition it is in. Is it not running because the battery is out of it, or is something else to blame? Without knowing the details, if things go wrong, you may not be able to recover your money in scrap.

Start with the obvious, fuel, oil, spark, coolant, etc. Put some stabilizer in the fuel before attempting to start it. Add new fuel as well.

[image]

As pointed out in the comments, if it doesn't start with a new battery, changed fluids and good spark plugs, you will be chasing problems down the rabbit hole. We cannot tell you how much repair costs will be.

Why don't you consider starting it where it currently is? It doesn't take very long to check the fluids and pop a new battery in it. If the seller refuses you the opportunity, perhaps it is best you avoid this deal.

You can move the vehicle with a heavy duty strap.

[image]

Vehicles usually have hooks to grab onto for towing. If you have difficulty locating them you can always wrap on to the front and rear axles.

Here is an example of how it is done. You must have someone in the vehicle being towed, and ensure the brakes are in working order. If you are concerned about damage, you can strap a tire to the rear section of the car that is doing the pulling.

[image]

You mentioned there may be difficulty with a low tire. If the vehicle is not near a compressor, you can bring a portable one to you!

Behold the Air Pig!

[image]

Depending on the size of Air Pig you have, and how low the tire is, you may be required to fill it up, (with a compressor) multiple times.

Comment: Could you paste this answer here? http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/24916/675 looks like we've got duplication. Thanks

Comment: Alright that's helpful , but for 400 dollars  I bought a shell at least and if I need to buy a new engine I will.  My only other concern  is inflating the last tire .

Comment: @user36537 You can inflate the tire with an air-pig. I will add an update.

Comment: I voted on the other one and this one.  You double hauled some upvotes!  :-)